# Efficient way to get the max and min values of each distinct keys in python pyspark rdd

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

so I  have some data like a rdd like this with key value pairs

```
rdd1. = [('a', 5), ('b', 6), ('c', 1), ('c', 5), ('a', 2), ('b', 8), ('c', 7), ('b', 9), ('a', 3)]
```

What is the most efficient way to return something like this with the max and min for each distinct key like this

```
rdd2 = [('a', (5, 2)), ('b', (6, 9)), ('c', (1, 7))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `groupByKey`

```
rdd1.groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x:(max(x),min(x))).collect()
```

---

```
[('a', (5, 2)), ('b', (9, 6)), ('c', (7, 1))]
```